# How do I pass a false value to a contextual filter on a boolean field?

Tags: views, 8

I'm inclined to think that I'm dealing with a defect, but I didn't see anything in the issue queue about it, so maybe it is a misunderstanding on my part.

I'm creating a view that will have a number of contextual filters. Some of them are on boolean fields. I've isolated my particular issue to a general problem with contextual filters on booleans, so I'm down to a single contextual filter on one of the booleans.

In the preview with contextual filters box, if I put a 1, I get the expected query:

SELECT node.nid AS node_nid, node_field_data.created AS node_field_data_created, node_field_data.nid AS nid
FROM 
{node_field_data} node_field_data

```
LEFT JOIN {node__field_partner_bha_member} node__field_partner_bha_member ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_partner_bha_member.entity_id AND (node__field_partner_bha_member.deleted = '0' AND node__field_partner_bha_member.langcode = node_field_data.langcode)
INNER JOIN {node} node ON node_field_data.nid = node.nid
WHERE (( (node__field_partner_bha_member.field_partner_bha_member_value = '1' ) )AND(( (node_field_data.status = '1') )))
ORDER BY node_field_data_created DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

However, if I put a 0, it simply excludes the filter from the query

```
SELECT node.nid AS node_nid, node_field_data.created AS node_field_data_created, node_field_data.nid AS nid
FROM 
{node_field_data} node_field_data
INNER JOIN {node} node ON node_field_data.nid = node.nid
WHERE (( (node_field_data.status = '1') ))
ORDER BY node_field_data_created DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

If I type a non boolean value there, e.g., 'bacon', it will give me the false results, but that seems like a hack.

Comment: I'm more inclined to think this is a bug, because if I have more than one, and pass something like 1/1/1 or 0/1/0, I get the expected query.

Comment: For my specific use case, I have a workaround, which is to explicitly pass true or false rather than omitting the filter, e.g.,
http://<mysite>/api/refine-block-items/1/0,1/1